# Find out the odd one in the diagram

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I'm solving puzzle from the book super excellent and intellegent test. Im stuck on these. Someone said answer should be 983. But how?  Can anyone tell me the right answer. thanks.
[image]

Comment: Is that the book with the ISBN 9780956670342 ?

Comment: @Pureferret 0956670342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because

> you can pair up all the other numbers as follows:
>
> 632 : 2836
>  315 : 5163
>  146 : 6741
>  385 : 5893
>
> In each pair, the four-digit number has its largest digit removed and then the remaining three digits are reversed to produce the corresponding three-digit number.  983 is the odd one out because there is no four-digit number to pair it with.

Answer (score 2):

I have another approach, but I will agree with @SQLnoob's logic as it is much more interesting.

The answer is :-

> 983.

Because :-

> 983 is the only prime number in the set. All other numbers are composites.